# Display only the shadow to a button in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Hi I wanted to know how to show only the shadow to a button and remove the text. I am not sure if this is possible.

For example in the pic below
[image]

I want to get rid on the text in the picture.

```
<button id="button-switch-1" class="device_cls control-metal-button modal-button cmb-tl cmb-plug modal-button-disabled" device_name="12.1" device_type="Light" device_id="1" state="on_bnt" board_id="12" room_type="Livingroom" room_id="1" control_call="roomcontrol">12.1</button>
```

and here is the css

```
.modal-button {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 179, 254, 0.77);
    background: url(../images/icon_bulb_on.png) 26px 20px no-repeat, url(../images/metal_btn.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 31px 49px, contain;
    width: 86px;
    height: 86px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow:0px 50px 0px #e1e2ed;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://cssdeck.com/labs/better-button

Comment: Can you provide us more informations or code please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? :

**html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <button type="button"><span id="buttontext">Click Me!</span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
button{
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
  background: transparent;
  border: none; 
}

#buttontext{
    position:relative;
    bottom:-20px;
}
```

Link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9u3vL7j/1/)

Comment: No I just want the text to be displayed below the button and not on the button

Comment: lemme try that i think it sue work...i tried adding br and this is working fine too

Comment: well you can change the amount of pixels here `bottom:-20px;` for better fit

Comment: i like it better i am trying it out i will accept that answer thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you are useing the html5 button:

```
<button class="shadow"></button>
```

leave the tag empty and if you are using the input type button then remove the value attribute:

```
<input class="shadow" type="button" />
```

then add the following css:

```
.shadow {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    width: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;
}
```

the result is an empty button with some shadow added:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/jwqa5a7q/)

you also can hide button text with the text-indent property like:

```
text-indent: -10000px;
```

Comment: If you see my buttons i want to get rid of the text in the button and keep the ones below it

Comment: Ok did you tried text-indent: -10000px; ore something like this